# Spark MLLib Collaborative Filtering with new user?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

how to use Spark MLLib Collaborative Filtering with new user or not logged user?

Comment: nothing out of the box.

Comment: Can Apache-Mahout to do this? Thanks!

Comment: no it can't. it's a theoretical issue and not framework related issue.

Comment: Oh. I understand, Thanks. and some good suggestions?

Comment: it's usually domain specific and the answer is quite broad to fit on the site. You might want to be looking for the New User Problem with Collaborative Filtering on the internet. You might find some approaches you can try. And as a matter of fact, I'm voting to close this question for being broad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111380/discussion-between-heramerom-and-eliasah).